# To print all the Armstrong number in the range of 1 to 500

Tags: c++

Well, I was given a task to print all the Armstrong numbers in the range of 1 to 500. I tried it myself applying the logic I know, I don't get any error in the program, but when I run it prints nothing. 
Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank You.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, i=1;
    cout << "\nThe Armstrong Numbers between 1 to 500 are : ";
    while(i <= 500)
    {
        a = i % 10;
        b = i % 100;
        b = (b - a) / 10;
        c = i % 100;
        if((a * a * a) + (b * b * b) + (c * c * c) == i)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
        }       
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it prints nothing, that means that `(a * a * a) + (b * b * b) + (c * c * c)` is never equal to `i`. Have you debugged it?

Comment: Also, your algorithm looks screwy. Read this over http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with the code! It really helped me, actually I am still a beginner and still improving on my skills! @Carcigenicate